# Notation: $\{\boldsymbol{e}_1,\boldsymbol{e}_2,\dots,\boldsymbol{e}_{|S|}\}$, $\{\boldsymbol{e}_s| s\in S\}$ or $\{\boldsymbol{e}_{s}\}_{s\in S}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to write a set consisting of a single vector $\boldsymbol{e}_s$ for each $s$ in a countable set $S$. I will write similar sets many times in my report, so I want something that does not take too much space. My idea was to write it as $\{\boldsymbol{e}_{s}\}_{s\in S}$, but I understand that this notation is usually used to denote a family rather than a set. Then I could write it as $\{\boldsymbol{e}_s\mid s\in S\}$ or $\{\boldsymbol{e}_1,\boldsymbol{e}_2,\dots,\boldsymbol{e}_{|S|}\}$, both of which are more standard set notation but also not as concise. What would be the best solution?

Comment: Note:  I edited your header so that the Latex could render it, but I don't understand what you mean by your indices.  Do you really mean $\{e_1,e_1, \cdots\}$?

Comment: @lulu, now the notation is as intended. As written in the post, the set should contain one (distinct) vector for each $s\in S$.

Comment: Should say:  the first attempt just looks bad.  Is $S$ meant to be countable?  Are $1,2,\cdots$ somehow meant to be elements of $S$?  I'd reject the first notation out of hand.  The other two look fine (and roughly equivalent), though it remains unclear what manner of thing $e_s$ is.  I gather you have some function in mind from $S$ to...something.  Then all the $e's$ are elements of the something.  But that should be clarified.

Comment: Note:  Just saying that $S$ is countable doesn't save the first notation.  You'd need to specify a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $S$ to do that.  As I say, I'd reject the first notation.

Comment: No, the indices are only meant to distinguish each vector from any other vector in the set. The important thing is that the cardinality of the set is equal to the cardinality of $S$, and that it is understood that it is a set of vectors.

Comment: I usually use $\{e_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ or similar. I think its clear enough.

Comment: I don't understand.  Just saying the $e's$ are "vectors" doesn't clarify things.  What vector space are they elements of?  the notation seems only to require that we have a map $e:S\to T$ for some set $T$ and then, for $s\in S$, we define $e_s=e(s)\in T$.  In that sense, $T$ could be a vector space, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: I think it's not clear what you are trying to ask here.  Perhaps you are asking the notation to do more than it should.  Why not write out exactly what it is you are trying to define?  That ought to clarify the best way to write it down.

Comment: Note, for instance, that "sets" are unordered by nature.  Thus, if $|S|=2$, then $\{e_1,e_2\}=\{e_2,e_1\}$.  "Vectors" by contrast are sometimes written as ordered sets.  Did you intend for your collections to be unordered?

Comment: I would write at the beginning of the report: " For any $s\in S$ denote $E_s$ the singleton $\{e_s\}.$" Then I would be allowed to use all over the document the short $E_s.$

Comment: @lulu, I am not trying to define a vector space nor define what the vectors are. The only thing I am trying to do is create a set of (yet undefined) vectors and the set should have the same size as $S$. I ask because I don't want to use notation that is confusing. For example, some may understand $\{\boldsymbol{e}_s\}_{s\in S}$ as a family rather than a set. Note that each $\boldsymbol{e}_s$ is a vector, i.e., I want to create a set that contains $|S|$ vectors.

Comment: Well, insisting that the elements are "vectors" but refusing to say what sort of vectors they are is confusing.  What difference does it make that they are vectors?  Can I just take them to be elements of my arbitrary set $T$?  What changes if I do that?

Comment: @lulu, then don't call them vectors. I want to create a set of elements $\boldsymbol{e}_s$ and I want exactly one element in that set for each $s\in S$.

Comment: In any case, your notation $s\mapsto e_s$ would appear to imply a specific assignment of an element $e\in T$ (whatever $T$ turns out to be) to an element in $S$.  Perhaps that's more than you wanted to specify.  In which case, just say that you have a set $\{e_i\}_{i\in S'}$ where $|S'|=|S|$.

Comment: Do you want to be able to recover which element of $S$ each $e_s$ corresponds to?  That's the point of asking about order.  Suppose, say, that $T=\{a,b,c\}$ and that $S=\{1,2\}$.  If my set is $\{c,b\}$ then I have successfully defined a set made of elements in $T$ of the same size as $S$, but I have no way of knowing if $c=e_1$ or $e_2$.

Comment: That's a good point, and I actually do need to associate an element $\boldsymbol{e}_s$ with an element $s\in S$ in some cases.